# How to deserialize XML number from misc formats

Tags: .net, xml

System we support uses XML data (that meet the same XSD schema) from several clients. Some clients use "," as numeric separator. Other clients use "."

Checking files against XSD-schemas is ok, then I try to deserialize files to extract data:

```
string xml ... <-- XML data 
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));    
MyType data = (MyType)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
// do something usefull with data
```

I get error for files where .net framework can't convert numbers with delimiter that differs from system one

```
 System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.   
 at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)...
```

How should I adopt my code to deserialize data in all possible number formats from all of our clients?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My recommendation is to deserialize it to a string, and then use the ``StringToNumber`` method that the ``XmlSerializer`` is passing the wrong NumberStyles into...